# React - Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In My react component,
My UI loads perfectly but there is console error which i wanted to fix error says - '`Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`' for below code.
Guide me how I can pass keys to `detailsContent`

```
render() {
    const header = (
        <div className={css.deviceDetailsBody}>
            <div className="sidebar__header">
                <div className="sidebar__title">
                    <div>
                        {hostname}
                        {this._renderCloser()}
                        <div className={"sidebar__subtitle"}>
                            <div className="toolsBar">
                                <div className="toolsBarlet">
                                    <div className="toolsItemNarrow">{deviceTypeView}</div>
                                    {complianceStatusView}
                                    <div className="toolsItemNarrow">{managementIpAddress}</div>
                                    {deviceUpTime}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    const horizontalLine = <div className="sidebar__horiz_line" />;
    const body = (
        <div className="body">
            {tabs}
            {tools}
        </div>
    );

    const detailsContent = [header, horizontalLine, body].map(
        currentComponent => currentComponent
    );

    return (
        <div>
            {sideBarShow && (
                <Sidebar {...sidebarProps}>
                    <div>{detailsContent}</div>
                </Sidebar>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Added the header, body code for more clarity.

Comment: I never used map like this before but Change like this see if works? 
const detailsContent = [header, horizontalLine, body].map( currentComponent => <div key={currentcomponent}>currentComponent</div> );

Comment: Its unlikely to work,just saying an idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to add keys

```
const detailsContent = [header, line, body].map(
  (element, index) => React.cloneElement(element, {key: index})
);
```

Comment: +one for your help and answer.

Comment: hey, what if there is one more component like this and it has the same keys? Wouldn't it led problems? how could we resolve that?

Comment: @OzanMudul Don't know, but you can quickly check it in stackblitz or codesandbox

Answer (score 8):

> Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

If using Components and not plain jsx elements, simply add a `key` prop to the `currentComponent` jsx. Note for simplicity I just used `index` as key.

```
const detailsContent = [header, horizontalLine, body].map(
  (CurrentComponent, index) => (<CurrentComponent key={index} />)
);
```

[See CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nifty-allen-h1p5g)

Using elements, please refer to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074043/8012206).

Comment: I think the items in the array are instances, you can not use them as `<CurrentComponent .../>`

Comment: if it is an element (as opposed to a component)? Do you assume `header` is a function or an element (for example `<div>header text</div>`? The original code is not clear, on one hand, the map function uses the name `currentComponent`, on the other, the items are not capitalized (`[Header, Line, Body]`)

Comment: @Meir, I assume all items in the array returns a JSX. The only catch is the name `currentComponent` should be `CurrentComponent`. Either way, the question was how to pass a key. :D

Comment: I agree that the issue is adding a key, but if elements can not be used like this, only components, so, JSX elements can not be 're-instantiated' using the`<CurrentComponent/>` syntax. I looked at your sample, it relates to components, the question might related to elements, in which case you need to clone it and add a key

Comment: @Meir, [I agree with you](https://codesandbox.io/embed/holy-sea-opk2e). +1 for your answer for elements.

Comment: @JosephD. It says `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string` `Check the render method ` `The above error occurred in the <div> component:`

Comment: @JavascriptCoder given the updated code, you are using elements. Please see previous comments how to make this work. i.e Meir's answer is how you should solve this using elements.

Comment: @JosephD. +1 for your answer and help.